# i don't know why it said "int object does not support item assignament"

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ("Tienes que adivinar el codigo de", cant_digitos, "digitos distintos")
propuesta = int(input("Ingrese una propuesta: "))

intentos = 1
while propuesta != codigo:
    intentos = intentos + 1
    aciertos = 0
    coincidencias = 0
    for propuesta[i] in range(cant_digitos):
        if propuesta[i] == codigo[i]:
            aciertos = aciertos + 1
        elif propuesta[i] in codigo:
            coincidencias = coincidencias + 1
    print ("Tu propuesta (", propuesta,") tiene ", aciertos, 
    "aciertos y ", coincidencias, "coincidencias")
    propuesta = int(input("Ingrese otra propuesta: "))
```

Comment: Because it's an `int` and you try to index it...

Comment: Please provide the traceback...

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
for propuesta[i] in range(cant_digitos):
   # ...
```

and `propuesta` is an integer. You can not assign to an element of an integer. For instance `2[0]` won't work as well.

Later in your code you write:

```
if propuesta[i] == codigo[i]:
    # ...
```

which is again invalid: you can not obtain an element from a number (since it is not a collection of digits, at least not in Python).

What do you expect it to return/assign? In case you are after the `i`-th digit, you can use:

```
# equivalent to propuesta[i]
(propuesta//(10**i))%10
```

to obtain the digit, and:

```
# equivalent to propuesta[i] = val (given 0 <= val <= 9)
propuesta += (val-((propuesta//(10**i))%10))*10**i
```

Comment: I don't understand :"v

Comment: @PageMario: please first update your question and explain what you actually aim to achieve with your code.

Comment: How can i send you a pic?

Comment: @PageMario: that's not how SO works. Why is it so hard to write three lines to explain how the input should map on the output?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm noob in this

Comment: oohhhh i get it, thank you very much and sorry for the inconvenience :)